# Warning: Undefined array key: Insertar y Consultar múltiples registros Base de Datos

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy haciendo un formulario en donde el usuario visualiza varios datos que ya tengo almacenados en mi base de datos, y el mismo usuario puede agregar varios comentarios que estos se tiene que subir a la BD.
Cuando hice las consultas, las hice con un `While` para que me duplicara la tabla dependiendo la cantidad de datos que tuviera almacenados, me dio muchos problemas al igual que con `Foreach`. Y decidí hacerlo registro por registro.

Aquí comienza el otro problema, cuando hice las consultas `(SELECT * FROM)` todo bien, me aparecían los datos que quería en mi tabla HTML, pero al momento de qurer insertar los datos que agregue el usuario, me lanza el siguiente error:

> Warning: Undefined array key "comentarios1"

Aquí les dejo el código, Si pueden ayudarme o si conocen alguna forma de hacerlo sin usar tanto código:

```php
<?php
include("conexion.php");
include("registrar.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>AUDITORIA</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <form action="registrar.php" method="post">
            <img src="secretariaDeSalud.jpg" height="150px"  align="left">
            <img src="LOGOnombre3.jpg" height="150px" align="right">
        <div>
            <h1><P align="center" style = "font-family: calibri"><b> Herramienta de auditoria de muestras HICPAC adaptada al INCMNSZ: 
                Reprocesamiento de endoscopios flexibles</b></P></h1>

            <hr size="3px" color="black"/>

           <div class="divmov">
           <p style="font-family: calibri"><b>Persona Evaluada: </b>
            <input type="text" name="evaluado" placeholder="Nombre">
            <?php  ?>
            <p style="font-family: calibri"><b>Evaluador: </b>
            <input type="text" name="evaluador1" placeholder="Auditor 1" size="30">
            <input type="text" name="evaluador2" placeholder="Auditor 2" size="30">
            <input type="text" name="evaluador3" placeholder="Auditor 3" size="30">
            <?php 

             ?>
           </div>
            <table align= "center" width="80%" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th width="50%"> Elementos de auditoría</th>
                    <th  width="15%">Si/No/NA</th>
                    <th>Comentarios/Acción</th>
                </tr>
  <!---------------CONSULTAS EN LA TABLA----------------->

                    <tr>
                    <td><<?php echo $arr1['NomElementoPrinc']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><?php echo $array1['NombreElemento']; ?></td>
                <td align ="center"> 
                    <input type="radio" name="si1" value="Si"> Si  
                    <input type="radio" name="no1" value="No"> No 
                    <input type="radio" name="na1" value="NA"> NA </td>
                <td><input name="comentarios1" placeholder="Agrega Comentarios" type="text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><?php echo $array2['NombreElemento']; ?></td>
                <td align ="center"> 
                    <input type="radio" name="si2" value="Si"> Si  
                    <input type="radio" name="no2" value="No"> No 
                    <input type="radio" name="na2" value="NA"> NA </td>
                <td><input name="comentarios2" placeholder="Agrega Comentarios" type="text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><?php echo $array3['NombreElemento']; ?></td>
                <td align ="center"> 
                    <input type="radio" name="si3" value="Si"> Si  
                    <input type="radio" name="no3" value="No"> No 
                    <input type="radio" name="na3" value="NA"> NA </td>
                <td><input name="comentarios3" placeholder="Agrega Comentarios" type="text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><?php echo $array4['NombreElemento']; ?></td>
                <td align ="center"> 
                    <input type="radio" name="si4" value="Si"> Si  
                    <input type="radio" name="no4" value="No"> No 
                    <input type="radio" name="na4" value="NA"> NA </td>
                <td><input name="comentarios4" placeholder="Agrega Comentarios" type="text"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                <td><?php echo $array5['NombreElemento']; ?></td>
                <td align ="center"> 
                    <input type="radio" name="si5" value="Si"> Si  
                    <input type="radio" name="no5" value="No"> No 
                    <input type="radio" name="na5" value="NA"> NA </td>
                <td><input name="comentarios5" placeholder="Agrega Comentarios" type="text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><?php echo $array6['NombreElemento']; ?></td>
                <td align ="center"> 
                    <input type="radio" name="si6" value="Si"> Si  
                    <input type="radio" name="no6" value="No"> No 
                    <input type="radio" name="na6" value="NA"> NA </td>
                <td><input name="comentarios6" placeholder="Agrega Comentarios" type="text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><?php echo $array7['NombreElemento']; ?></td>
                <td align ="center"> 
                    <input type="radio" name="si7" value="Si"> Si  
                    <input type="radio" name="no7" value="No"> No 
                    <input type="radio" name="na7" value="NA"> NA </td>
                <td><input name="comentarios7" placeholder="Agrega Comentarios" type="text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><?php echo $array8['NombreElemento']; ?></td>
                <td align ="center"> 
                    <input type="radio" name="si8" value="Si"> Si  
                    <input type="radio" name="no8" value="No"> No 
                    <input type="radio" name="na8" value="NA"> NA </td>
                <td><input name="comentarios8" placeholder="Agrega Comentarios" type="text"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                <td><?php echo $array9['NombreElemento']; ?></td>
                <td align ="center"> 
                    <input type="radio" name="si9" value="Si"> Si  
                    <input type="radio" name="no9" value="No"> No 
                    <input type="radio" name="na9" value="NA"> NA </td>
                <td><input name="comentarios9" placeholder="Agrega Comentarios" type="text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><?php echo $array10['NombreElemento']; ?></td>
                <td align ="center"> 
                    <input type="radio" name="si10" value="Si"> Si  
                    <input type="radio" name="no10" value="No"> No 
                    <input type="radio" name="na10" value="NA"> NA </td>
                <td><input name="comentarios10" placeholder="Agrega Comentarios" type="text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><?php echo $array11['NombreElemento']; ?></td>
                <td align ="center"> 
                    <input type="radio" name="si11" value="Si"> Si  
                    <input type="radio" name="no11" value="No"> No 
                    <input type="radio" name="na11" value="NA"> NA </td>
                <td><input name="comentarios11" placeholder="Agrega Comentarios" type="text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><?php echo $array12['NombreElemento']; ?></td>
                <td align ="center"> 
                    <input type="radio" name="si12" value="Si"> Si  
                    <input type="radio" name="no12" value="No"> No 
                    <input type="radio" name="na12" value="NA"> NA </td>
                <td><input name="comentarios12" placeholder="Agrega Comentarios" type="text"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                <td><?php echo $array13['NombreElemento']; ?></td>
                <td align ="center"> 
                    <input type="radio" name="si13" value="Si"> Si  
                    <input type="radio" name="no13" value="No"> No 
                    <input type="radio" name="na13" value="NA"> NA </td>
                <td><input name="comentarios13" placeholder="Agrega Comentarios" type="text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><?php echo $array14['NombreElemento']; ?></td>
                <td align ="center"> 
                    <input type="radio" name="si14" value="Si"> Si  
                    <input type="radio" name="no14" value="No"> No 
                    <input type="radio" name="na14" value="NA"> NA </td>
                <td><input name="comentarios14" placeholder="Agrega Comentarios" type="text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><?php echo $array15['NombreElemento']; ?></td>
                <td align ="center"> 
                    <input type="radio" name="si15" value="Si"> Si  
                    <input type="radio" name="no15" value="No"> No 
                    <input type="radio" name="na15" value="NA"> NA </td>
                <td><input name="comentarios15" placeholder="Agrega Comentarios" type="text"></td>
                </tr>
                </table> 


              <div class="divtabla">
             </div>
              <div align="right">
             <button class="button-43" name="boton" role="button"><b>ENVIAR</b></button>         
            </div>
         </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

APARTADO PHP

```php
<?php include("conexion.php");

//----------------Consultar Subelemetos--------------------------

$query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM elementos WHERE idelementos = 1");
$array1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

$query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM elementos WHERE idelementos = 2");
$array2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

$query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM elementos WHERE idelementos = 3");
$array3 = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

$query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM elementos WHERE idelementos = 4");
$array4 = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

$query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM elementos WHERE idelementos = 5");
$array5 = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

$query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM elementos WHERE idelementos = 6");
$array6 = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

$query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM elementos WHERE idelementos = 7");
$array7 = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

$query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM elementos WHERE idelementos = 8");
$array8 = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

$query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM elementos WHERE idelementos = 9");
$array9 = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

$query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM elementos WHERE idelementos = 10");
$array10 = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

$query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM elementos WHERE idelementos = 11");
$array11 = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

$query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM elementos WHERE idelementos = 12");
$array12 = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

$query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM elementos WHERE idelementos = 13");
$array13 = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

$query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM elementos WHERE idelementos = 14");
$array14 = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

$query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM elementos WHERE idelementos = 15");
$array15 = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

//-------------------Inserta Comentarios------------------------------------
    $comentario1 = $_POST['comentarios1'];
    $consulta = "INSERT INTO comentarios(comentario) VALUES ('$comentario1')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

    $comentario2 = $_POST['comentarios2'];
    $consulta = "INSERT INTO comentarios(comentario) VALUES ('$comentario2')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

    $comentario3 = $_POST['comentarios3'];
    $consulta = "INSERT INTO comentarios(comentario) VALUES ('$comentario3')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

    $comentario4 = $_POST['comentarios4'];
    $consulta = "INSERT INTO comentarios(comentario) VALUES ('$comentario4')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
```

Comment: ¿Qué muestra un `var_dump($_POST);` en tu contexto? Y, ¿por qué tantas consultas que se parecen, no puedes escribir una consulta con múltiples criterios, algo como `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE idelementos IN(1,2,3...)` y lo mismo para los `INSERT` ¿?

Comment: ¿Cómo estás enviando el formulario?  No tienes un botón del **type** submit en ninguna parte.  Si lo haces con javascript debes agregarlo a la pregunta para que podamos ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí dejo tu código refactorizado sin tantas repeticiones (no está probado, puede tener pequeños fallos):

```php
<?php
include("conexion.php");
include("registrar.php");

// calculamos las filas
$salida_radios = '';
foreach($array as $idelemento => $datos) {
    $salida_radios .= '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$datos['NombreElemento'].'</td>
            <td align ="center"> 
                <input type="radio" name="radio_'.$idelemento.'" value="Si"> Si  
                <input type="radio" name="radio_'.$idelemento.'" value="No"> No 
                <input type="radio" name="radio_'.$idelemento.'" value="NA"> NA
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="comentarios'.$idelemento.'" placeholder="Agrega Comentarios" type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
    ';
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>AUDITORIA</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="registrar.php" method="post">
        <img src="secretariaDeSalud.jpg" height="150px"  align="left">
        <img src="LOGOnombre3.jpg" height="150px" align="right">
        <div>
            <h1><P align="center" style = "font-family: calibri"><b> Herramienta de auditoria de muestras HICPAC adaptada al INCMNSZ: Reprocesamiento de endoscopios flexibles</b></P></h1>
            <hr size="3px" color="black"/>
            <div class="divmov">
                <p style="font-family: calibri"><b>Persona Evaluada: </b>
                <input type="text" name="evaluado" placeholder="Nombre">
                <p style="font-family: calibri"><b>Evaluador: </b>
                <input type="text" name="evaluador1" placeholder="Auditor 1" size="30">
                <input type="text" name="evaluador2" placeholder="Auditor 2" size="30">
                <input type="text" name="evaluador3" placeholder="Auditor 3" size="30">
            </div>
            <table align= "center" width="80%" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th width="50%"> Elementos de auditoría</th>
                    <th  width="15%">Si/No/NA</th>
                    <th>Comentarios/Acción</th>
                </tr>
  <!------------------------------------CONSULTAS EN LA TABLA------------------------------------------>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $arr1['NomElementoPrinc']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?= $salida_radios; ?>
            </table> 
            <div class="divtabla">
            </div>
            <div align="right">
                <button type="submit" class="button-43" name="boton" role="button"><b>ENVIAR</b></button>         
            </div>
         </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

```php
<!-------------------------------APARTADO PHP----------------->
<?php include("conexion.php");

//---------------------Consultar Subelemetos-------------------------------

$query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM elementos WHERE idelementos < 16 ORDER BY idelementos";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $array[$row['idelementos']] = $row;
}

//-------------------Inserta Comentarios------------------------------------

foreach($_POST as $clave => $valor) {
    // PHP anterior a la versión 8
    // if (strpos($clave, 'comentarios') !== false) {
    // PHP 8
    if (str_contains($clave, 'comentarios')) {
        $consulta = "INSERT INTO comentarios(comentario) VALUES ($valor)";
        $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
    }
}
```

### Explicación

Repites demasiadas cosas, así que he procurado usar bucles que eliminen tanta repetición.

Para comprender mejor estos cambios, empecemos por como genero un solo array que contiene todos los datos de los id que quieres consultar:

He hecho esto:

```php
//---------------------Consultar Subelemetos-------------------------------
$query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM elementos WHERE idelementos < 16 ORDER BY idelementos";
$array = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $array[$row['idelementos']] = $row;
}
```

donde:

- He cambiado todas esas consultas por una sola que me devuelva todos los registros a la vez:

```sql
SELECT * FROM elementos WHERE idelementos < 16 ORDER BY idelementos
```

de este modo los obtengo todos, ordenados por idelementos.

- He inicializado una variable denominada $array que usaremos después en el bucle que irá a continuación:

```php
$array = [];
```

- Luego voy recorriendo los resultados de la consulta, uno a uno, en este bucle, asignando en cada ciclo a variable **$row** la fila recorrida completa:

```php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
```

- Dentro de ese bucle agrego a la variable $array la fila completa, indexada por el número de la columna **idelemento**:

```php
$array[$row['idelementos']] = $row;
```

Nota: Se entiende que los **idelementos** son únicos, es decir, no se repiten, pues en caso contrario estariamos sobreescribiendolos y sólo permaneceria el último encontrado.

Una vez terminados los ciclos, el contenido de esa variable $array podría parecerse a esto:

```php
$array = [
    '1' => [
        'idelemento'=> '1',
        'columna2' => 'valor columna2',
        'columna3' => 'valor columna3',
        etc...
    ],
    '2' => [
        'idelemento' => '2',
        'columna2' => 'valor columna2',
        'columna3' => 'valor columna3',
        etc...
    ],
    etc... (hasta llegar al 15)
]
```

Ahora que ya tenemos este array vamos a ponerlo en la tabla, y para ello lo podemos calcular previamente y almacenarlo en una variable, que en este caso he llamado `$salida_radios`, y lo he hecho de esta forma:

```php
// calculamos las filas
$salida_radios = '';
foreach($array as $idelemento => $datos) {
    $salida_radios .= '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$datos['NombreElemento'].'</td>
            <td align ="center"> 
                <input type="radio" name="radio_'.$idelemento.'" value="Si"> Si  
                <input type="radio" name="radio_'.$idelemento.'" value="No"> No 
                <input type="radio" name="radio_'.$idelemento.'" value="NA"> NA
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="comentarios'.$idelemento.'" placeholder="Agrega Comentarios" type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
    ';
}
```

donde

- primero inicializamos la variable de salida:

```php
$salida_radios = '';
```

- después recorremos el $array que ya tenemos con todos los datos y la estructura explicada anteriormente con un **foreach**:

```php
foreach($array as $idelemento => $datos) {
```

donde en cada ciclo, vamos a extraer su índice en la variable `$idelemento` y su contenido (que es otro array que contiene todos los datos de todas las columnas como ves más arriba) lo he llamados `$datos`:

```php
$array as $idelemento => $datos
```

Y ahora solo queda ir agregando contenido a la variable $salida_radios de este modo:

```php
    $salida_radios .= '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$datos['NombreElemento'].'</td>
            <td align ="center"> 
                <input type="radio" name="radio_'.$idelemento.'" value="Si"> Si  
                <input type="radio" name="radio_'.$idelemento.'" value="No"> No 
                <input type="radio" name="radio_'.$idelemento.'" value="NA"> NA
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="comentarios'.$idelemento.'" placeholder="Agrega Comentarios" type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
    ';
```

Fíjate que estoy usando el mismo **name** en cada ciclo, el cual queda compuesto por la palabra `radio_` más el número de índice ($idelemento) del registro recorrido en cada ciclo:

```php
name="radio_'.$idelemento.'"
```

Así es como deben ser los botones de radio que son autoexcluyentes entre sí, para que solo se envie un valor que se corresponderá con el seleccionado bajo el mismo **name**. En este caso los name se llamarán *radio_1*, *radio_2*, etc.

Tal como lo hacias tu estabas enviando siempre todas los name si1, no1, na1, si2, no2, na2, etc... y tendrias más problemas para saber cual de ellos ha sido seleccionado.

Por otra parte, fíjate como localizo y saco el valor de la columna **NombreElemento** de los datos en cada registro de cada ciclo:

```php
<td>'.$datos['NombreElemento'].'</td>
```

En cuanto al campo comentarios, lo genero así en cada ciclo:

```php
<input name="comentarios'.$idelemento.'" placeholder="Agrega Comentarios" type="text">
```

y así pasará a llamarse tal como lo tenias, es decir, `comentarios1`, `comentarios2`, etc...

Recuerda que todo eso se va almacenando en la variable $salida_radios, que como puedes ver he puesto en la tabla de este modo en el mismo lugar donde empezabas tu a poner todas esas repeticiones de botones de radio y comentarios:

```php
<?= $salida_radios; ?>
```

(el conjunto de símbolos `<?=` es una abreviatura de `<?php echo`, por lo tanto lo que estoy haciendo es un `echo` de lo que contenga la variable $salida_radios que hemos rellenado antes, que son todas las filas de la tabla con los botones de radio y comentarios).

Y ahora vamos con la inserción de comentarios, donde verás que he cambiado los cuatro que has puesto (imagino que habia más, hasta los 15 que parece que quieres poner) por esto:

```php
//-------------------Inserta Comentarios------------------------------------
foreach($_POST as $clave => $valor) {
    // PHP anterior a la versión 8
    // if (strpos($clave, 'comentarios') !== false) {
    // PHP 8
    if (str_contains($clave, 'comentarios')) {
        $consulta = "INSERT INTO comentarios(comentario) VALUES ($valor)";
        $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
    }
}
```

donde lo que hago es evaluar cada dato recibido por **POST** y si su clave contiene la palabra `comentarios`:

```php
if (str_contains($clave, 'comentarios')) {
```

entonces hago la inserción en la base de datos dentro de la columna *comentarios* de la tabla *comentarios*:

```php
$consulta = "INSERT INTO comentarios(comentario) VALUES ($valor)";
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
```

Y con esto terminan los cambios para refactorizar tu código y que no sea tan costoso de mantener.

Aún así, volviendo al problema inicial, diría que el error de `undefined array key` viene por otros motivos, que pueden ser:

1. No tienes un botón del tipo "submit" que envie el formulario. El único botón que tienes es este:

```html
<button class="button-43" name="boton" role="button"><b>ENVIAR</b></button>
```

el cual aparentemente, y basándome sólo en el código que has aportado en la pregunta no parece que haga el **submit** que se necesita para enviar el formulario con los datos, sino que seguramente simplemente te redirecciona a la página que hayas puesto en el **form action** sin enviar los datos.

2. Quizás si que usas javascript para detectar la pulsación del botón con la clase "button-43", pero lo dudo y además no lo has puesto en la pregunta.

Por lo tanto, lo he cambiado por uno del tipo **submit** que **sí** va a enviar los datos correctamente:

```html
<button type="submit" class="button-43" name="boton" role="button"><b>ENVIAR</b></button>
```

Y con eso ya estamos para darte una respuesta a tu pregunta.

Si has leído hasta aquí házmelo saber con un comentario, tengo curiosidad por ver cuanto rollo has sido capaz de soportar :-)  Y si no te has leído todo esto vas a ignorar el porque de todos esos cambios y no vas a aprender nada nuevo, aunque saldrás del paso supongo.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, me sirvió mucho tu código hermano. Solo que soy muy novato en la programación y mas aun en PHP ya que casi no lo eh visto, y al momento de visualizar tu código, hay algunas funciones que no conocía y sigo sin conocer, por ejemplo "foreach", esa parte no la conocía pero me puse a investigar y ya se maso menos como es su funcionamiento, me pasa lo mismo con los arreglos y "str_contains", etc. Me gustaría localizarte para saber maso menos si impartes algún curso o algo parecido, para obtener mas conocimiento de PHP, HTML y CSS al igual que JavaScript

Comment: Y con respecto al código, Si me cargo la pagina bien, pero al momento de agregar un comentario, este no me lo sube a la base de datos, pero no me marca ningún error. Solo no sube nada a la base de datos.

Comment: No doy clases, lo siento. Respecto al problema de la inserción, quizás no estás usando PHP 8 y entonces str_contains() no funciona, por eso puse tambien esta línea: `// if (strpos($clave, 'comentarios') !== false) {`  para que la sustituyeras en caso de que no uses PHP 8 o superior.  Prueba y ya me dirás.

Comment: Amigo una pregunta, Como estas indicándole un método POST en el foreach de el apartado de la inserción de comentarios... Si por lo que veo no tiene como identificar ese método POST con el name="comentarios'.$idelemento.'"
Pienso que a lo mejor, por eso no me sube nada a la Base de datos

Comment: Teóricamente esto: `if (str_contains($clave, 'comentarios')) {` localiza el POST con clave `comentariosX` porque tan solo busca que la clave contenga la palabra **comentarios** dándole igual lo que lleve de más, por lo tanto aunque tengas **comentarios1** o **comentarios1000** te lo tendría que coger bien

Comment: si acaso, antes de esa línea del condicional, escribe esto:  `print_r($_POST);` y mira a ver que datos estas enviando por POST, y si ves algun **comentariosX** entonces tendria que entrar bien en ese condicional y hacer el INSERT.  Si no lo hace será por alguna otra causa.

Comment: Ya hice eso hermano, y al parecer si me cacha todo lo que escribo en los comentarios, pero no los sube a la base de datos, ya cheque todo y todo esta bien, el nombre de la base de datos, nombre de la tabla, ya leí el código varias veces pero no encuentro la falla. De igual manera ya le intente con la otra linea de código (Respecto a las versiones de PHP) y tampoco me deja.